# ckeditor upload images, to fix image size

Tags: php, image, upload, ckeditor

we have been using ckeditor for some while, and now, wish to load a template (it has, say, 3 images) to ckeditor and let users to right click and change images

say, each of the 3 images have different width and height, for example

img1 : 200w x 300h

img2 : 350w x 250h

img3 : 400w x 350h

We wish, if user clicks img1, then resize user's image to max. 200w or 300h, if clicks img2, then resize user's image to max 350w or 250h, so that it won't expand the template

I wish it's a script resize but not HTML restrict

how can we use the uploader to resize different image blocks flexibly?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've already configured the basic file Uploads, you can use the [ImageCrop plugin](http://www.uritec.es/portal/seccion.aspx?N=60) to allow the users to crop/resize their images when they upload it from their computer, or if they pick an existing image from their browser to perform the same operations, and you can define in the configuration of the editor which sizes are allowed.